# NGINX not make sense, downloading PHP script when rename

Tags: nginx

The only thing I do was

```
    mv test.php betterName.php
```

no permission changes, nothing changed.  Them rename in the NGINX configuration... FROM

```
    location  @rule {
            rewrite ^rule([a-z0-9]+)$
            /test.php?obj=$1            last;
    }
```

TO

```
    location  @rule {
            rewrite ^rule([a-z0-9]+)$
            /betterName.php?obj=$1            last;
    }
```

and `service nginx restart`.

It is magic: when I "undo" the rename process, `mv betterName.php test.php` and back old location, all working fine again.

---

Using fresh UBUNTU 16 LTS with fresh NGINX.

---

### NOTES

The real-life  conf-nginx-script that I am using seems,

```
server {
        server_name etc.etc;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/etc.etc.access_log;
        root /var/www/etc.etc/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @idResolver;
        }

        location ^~ /issn {
                try_files $uri @issnResolver;
        }

        location  @idResolver {
                rewrite ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$
                /index.php?obj=$1            last;
        }
        location  @issnResolver {
                rewrite ^/?issn[/:]?([xX0-9\-]+)[/:]?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
                /test.php?obj=$1&cmd=$2            last;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
} #end server
```

... More real-life dumps for @RichardSmith comment:

```
ll /var/www/etc.etc/
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 15 09:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  9 09:07 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data  5860 Feb 14 21:04 index.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data   291 Feb 15 09:24 test.php
```

And real-life name is `issn_resolver.php`, so I do `mv test.php issn_resolver.php`.

Comment: Is that the only place where `test.php` is mentioned in your configuration files? Your regular expression as written will not match **any** URIs.

Comment: Hi @SebastianBrosch , I think I not understand what you say about `N`, I copy/paste the full conf, see edited question.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith, yes, the "only place" ... the other place that I can imagine is the *default conf.*, there are no `grep test`.

Comment: What's the "better name"? I bet it starts with `/issn...`

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, I edited for you see the `ls` dumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI `/issn_resolver.php` will match the `location ^~ /issn` block and not the `location ~ \.php$` block as intended. Which results in the PHP script being downloaded rather than being executed.

The `^~` operator makes a prefix location take higher precedence that all of the regular expression location blocks.

If the `^~` operator is unnecessary - remove it - otherwise, find a name for the PHP script that does not begin with `issn`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

---

To redirect all URIs that begin with `issn` to a given script, either:

1) Combine the two `locations` into one, and use a PHP script name that does not begin with `issn`:

```
location ^~ /issn {
    rewrite ^/?issn[/:]?([xX0-9\-]+)[/:]?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
    /test.php?obj=$1&cmd=$2            last;
}
```

Or:

2) Hardwire the name of the PHP file:

```
location ^~ /issn {
    rewrite ^/?issn[/:]?([xX0-9\-]+)[/:]?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
    /?obj=$1&cmd=$2            break;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/test.php        
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Notice the `rewrite...break` is used to capture the query string for the PHP script, but no longer required to name the script file. The script file is named by overriding the value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` from that imported from the `snippets` file.

Comment: Thanks, now is making sense!

Comment: If I never use  `$uri` as a file, how to express `location` to obtain same behaviour? (need only to redirect the string to the php).

Comment: I have added a couple of options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect!

Comment: PS: I have problems on implement-and-test your suggestions, so there are a new quetion, now about  NGINX-caching https://stackoverflow.com/q/48845250/287948